# AWS Lambda create presigned URL for S3 using invoked credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a presigned URL for a S3 bucket in AWS Lambda (Python 3.7) that is signed using the credentials of the person that invoked the Lambda function via API Gateway.

The flow would be:

1. User sends HTTP request to API Gateway, which is secured using Amazon Cognito.
2. The API gateway then invokes a Lambda function, which knows who the original user is.
3. The Lambda function then generates a presigned URL for the S3 bucket using the original user's credentials, rather than the default Lambda role etc.

I have managed to generate a presigned URL using the default Lambda role, just haven't managed to make this use the original user's credentials. Any direction in this would be great, thanks.

Comment: If the client has AWS credentials, why not just create the signed URL locally on the client (using the relevant SDK or roll-your-own signing)?

Comment: I've tried doing this, but the app continues to crash. I am developing this in Xamarin.Forms application, and having issues with Identity Pools unfortunately, so this seems to be the way to fix it.

Comment: Without additional information, it's going to be impossible to help with "the app continues to crash". I'm not familiar with Xamarin and the AWS .Net SDK but it looks like [it is supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/Welcome.html).

Comment: Hi @jarmod, I have now posted another question that may be more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694298/identity-pools-in-net-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can pass the access token, you may generste temporary credentials using [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html)